# Access nested property from another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, object-destructuring

I am confused on how this code below has access to a nested property. The `addLayer` function takes in a object which has a nested property `textfield` which comes from the above `addSource` method's `properties.storeId`.
I am confused on how the `textfield` can be written as `{storeId}`. The object is not destructed anywhere therefore how can it be written like this?

```
const loadmap = () => {
  map.on("load", () => {

    map.addSource("point", {
      type: "geojson",
      data: {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [
          {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [-71.157895, 42.707741],
            },
            properties: {
              storeId: "0001",
              icon: "store"
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });

    map.addLayer({
      id: "points",
      type: "symbol",
      source: "point", // reference the data source
      layout: {
        "icon-image": "airfield-11", // reference the image
        "text-field": "{storeId}",
      },
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: It may be part of the `map` library? Otherwise `"{storeId}"` is just a string.

Comment: If it's part of the library can you access a nested property in this syntax? The ```storeID``` property shows as 0001 when ran so it is definitedly working

Answer (score 0):

{storeId} between double quotations is just a string,

otherwise it's a shorthand for

```
let object={storeId:storeId}
```

another example:

```
let name="erfan"
let obj = {name} /// equivalent to {name:name}
```